# using O_TMPFILE to clean up huge pages... or other methods?

Tags: linux, file, kernel, mmap, huge-pages

My program is using huge pages. For doing, it open files as follows:

```
oflags = O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC;
fd = open(filename, oflag, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH);
```

Where `filename` is in the hugetlb file system.
That works. My program can then `mmap()` the created file descriptors. But if my program gets killed, the files remain... and in the huge page filesystem, remaining files is blocked memory, as shown by the following command (876 != 1024):

```
cat /proc/meminfo  | grep Huge

AnonHugePages:    741376 kB
HugePages_Total:    1024
HugePages_Free:      876
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
```

So, as my program is not sharing the file to anyone else, it made sense to me to create temporary files using the O_TMPFILE flag.
So I tried:

```
oflags = O_RDWR | O_TMPFILE;
fd = open(pathname, oflag, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH);
```

where pathname is the hugetlbfs moint point.
That fails (for a reason I cannot explain) with the following error:

```
open failed for /dev/hugepages: Operation not supported
```

Why? and more to the point: How can I guarantee that all huge pages my program is using get freed?

Yes: I could catch some signals (e.g. `SIGTERM`); but not all (`SIGKILL`)

Yes: I could `unlink()` the file as soon as possible using the first approach, but what if `SIGKILL` is received between `open()` and `unlink()`.

Kernels like guaranties. So do I. What is the proper methods to guarantees 100% cleanup regardless on when or how my program terminates.

Comment: Can't you simply call `mmap( NULL, bytes, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_HUGETLB, -1, 0 );` instead of using the `hugetlbfs` file system?  Per [the huge TLB documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/hugetlbpage.txt):  "Also, it is important to note that **no such mount command is required** if
applications are going to use only shmat/shmget system calls or mmap with
MAP_HUGETLB."

Comment: @Andrew: My program shares the memory between different processes, so I need the file descriptors. Your comment make sense, I should have specified this in my original question.

Comment: Assuming your program would just recreate the file if the file gets cleaned up after your process might be killed, does reusing an existing `hugetlbfs` file work?  If you're just going to recreate the file, does it really matter if it's not cleaned up?

Comment: yes. it does matter. Files are created with different names and sizes at each run. But my question was more a theoretical one: unlinking the files immediately after open() and before mmap() works and the chance to be sigkilled in between is minimal. But I don't like this "99%" approach and I am a bit surprised it does not look like there is a 100% answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like O_TMPFILE is not implemented yet for hugetlbfs; indeed, this option requires support of the underlying file-system:

> O_TMPFILE  requires  support by the underlying filesystem; only a subset of Linux filesystems provide that support.  In the initial implementation, support was provided in the ex2, ext3, ext4, UDF, Minix, and shmem filesystems.  XFS support was added
>                 in Linux 3.15.

This is confirmed by looking at the kernel source code where there's no *inode_ops->tmpfile()* implementation in hugetlbfs.

I believe that the right answer here is to work on this implementation...

---

I noticed your comment about the unlink() option, however, maybe the following approach is not that risky:

- open the file (by name) with TRUNCATE (so you can assume its size is 0)
- unlink it
- mmap() it with your target size

If your program gets killed in the middle, worst case is to leave an empty file.

Comment: hmmm does not look right, really. your suggestion is what I am doing right now. Not that I really like it though... Thanks